# Auto-renaming a var, (similar to how to MS windows uses numbers at the end for duplidates)

Tags: javascript

I need your help.

How can I rename a var and add a number at the end of it, starting at 2 and then so fourth.

Basically, im doing some DB work in the backend and if a duplicate record (file number) is detected then I will have a script to rename var:

So in this scenario, a duplicate filenumber was detected, so javascript will rename the var (starting at 2) and then so fourth and so fourth.

So faily simple so far, use javascript to add a number -2 at the end of file number and compute the new result.

```
var x = filenumber

    x = filenumber-2
```

(this is where the super algebra takes place, how do I accomplish this?)

Examples:

```
if (dbresult already exists) { then rename var x to filenumber-2 }

If (x already equals filenumber-2) { then rename var x to filenumber-3 }

If (x already equals filenumber-3) { then rename var x to filenumber-4 }

If (x already equals filenumber-4) { then rename var x to filenumber-5 }

and so fourth...
```

Comment: Have you considered using arrays? Are you just trying to create a unique string name? Eg: File01, File02?

Comment: Something like MS Windows uses, so if you were to copy the same file number to a directory, it auto renames to filenumber(1) ect.

Comment: You can't rename variables. You can create a copy of a variable with a new name, and then never use the old variable again, but I don't think that is what you're trying to achieve.  The problem is a bit vague.  If all you want to do is ensure no two filenames are the same (such as in Windows), then you would check if the value of a variable already exists and then change the value of that variable based on the result.

Comment: @Stieffers but the value of the result, has to be sequential. So im guessing some sort of function to account for, and read the number -2,-3,-4 at the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [`while` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while). Presuming you have your file data in `fileData` and its name in `originalFileName`

```
// Your initial decrement
var decrement = -2;
// Create a tentative copy of the filename
var filename  = originalFileName

// If it exists in dbresult, execute the code below. Repeat until filename isn't there
while( filename in dbresult ){
    // Apply the decrement
    filename = originalFileName + decrement;
    // Reduce the decrement
    decrement--;
    // while loops can be infinite unless you give them an escape clause
    if( decrement < 1000 ){
        break;
    }
}

dbresult[ filename ] = file;
```

Comment: You weren't calling the `test` function, you hadn't defined `file` or `filename`, and `dbresult` was a string (I was expecting it to be the database representation object, where you were storing keys). [Here's a fixed version](http://jsfiddle.net/barney/zdfSN/).